# Oracle SQL data migration row to column based in month fails due to type

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

```
TABLE1

CODE    RATE1   type    MONTH
A       0       Acc1    201906
A       0       Acc1    201907
A       0       Acc1    201908
A       1       Acc1    201909
A       1       Acc1    201910
A       1       Acc1    201911
A       1       Acc1    201912
A       1       Acc1    202001
A       1       Acc1    202002
A       1       Acc1    202003
A       1       Acc1    202004
A       1       Acc1    202005
A       1       Acc1    202006
A       1       Acc1    202007
A       1       Acc1    202008
A       1       Acc1    202009

A       0       Acc2    201906
A       0       Acc2    201907
A       0       Acc2    201908
A       1       Acc2    201909
A       1       Acc2    201910
A       1       Acc2    201911
A       1       Acc2    201912
A       1       Acc2    202001
A       1       Acc2    202002
A       1       Acc2    202003
A       1       Acc2    202004
A       1       Acc2    202005
A       1       Acc2    202006
A       1       Acc2    202007
A       1       Acc2    202008
A       1       Acc2    202009
```

TABLE2

```
CODE   RATE2    MONTH
A       10       202001
A       10       202002
A       10       202003
A       10       202004
```

I am working on migrating data from old system to new system. As part of old system data maintained per month and will update the same row if data updated and table contains one row for a month I am migrating to news system and it contains start date and end date to make the active record . So on update new data needs to inserted and updated the old row end date

I have couple of table which I need to join and find the start date and end date based on rate1 and rate2.
My first table contains the data for all the months and second table data available untill its active on decativate data will not be available. if rate available and we consider as 0.

My expected output

```
CODE    RATE1   RATE2   Type    START_DT    END_DT
A       0       0       Acc1    201906      201908
A       1       0       Acc1    201909      201912
A       1       10      Acc1    202001      202004
A       1       0       Acc1    202005      202009
A       0       0       Acc2    201906      201908
A       1       0       Acc2    201909      201912
A       1       10      Acc2    202001      202004
A       1       0       Acc2    202005      202009
```

But I am getting below result 23 rows .

```
    select code1, rate1, rate2, type, min(month) start_dt, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by code1 order by max(month) desc) = 1 then 999912 else max(month) end end_dt
from (
    select t1.month, code1, rate1, rate2, type,
        row_number() over(partition by code1 order by t1.month) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by code1, type, rate1, rate2, type order by t1.month) rn2
    from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.code1 = t2.code2 and t1.month = t2.month
) t
group by code1, rate1, rate2, type, rn1 - rn2
order by start_dt
```

Please find my query in this URL https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4f77cd13967c1c5a74efcacfb3d3a22

Thanks in advance.

Please comment if you need more informations

Answer (score 0):

You are rather close to solving this gaps-and-islands assignment. The problem is with column `type`. It needs to go the the `partition by` clause of both window functions, so it is consistent with the outer `group by`.

This gives you the result you want:

```
select code1, rate1, coalesce(rate2, 0), type, min(month) start_dt, max(month) end_dt
from (
    select t1.month, t1.code1, t1.rate1, t2.rate2, type,
        row_number() over(partition by t1.code1, t1.type order by t1.month) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by t1.code1, t1.type, t1.rate1, t2.rate2 order by t1.month) rn2
    from table1 t1 
    left join table2 t2 on t1.code1 = t2.code2 and t1.month = t2.month
) t
group by code1, rate1, rate2, type, rn1 - rn2
order by type, start_dt
```

Notes:

- I am unsure about the logic you want to implement with the date casting in the outer query, and it does not seem consistent with the desired results, so I removed it
- do qualify all columns in the subquery with the table they belong to; this avoids ambiguity
- I also fixed the outer `order by` clause so results are returned in the desired order, and used `coalesce()` to default missing `rate2`s to `0`

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d713317a5cb0e6728e1ca8c5364968cc)**:

```
CODE1 | RATE1 | COALESCE(RATE2,0) | TYPE | START_DT | END_DT
:---- | ----: | ----------------: | :--- | -------: | -----:
A     |     0 |                 0 | Acc1 |   201906 | 201908
A     |     1 |                 0 | Acc1 |   201909 | 201912
A     |     1 |                10 | Acc1 |   202001 | 202004
A     |     1 |                 0 | Acc1 |   202005 | 202009
A     |     0 |                 0 | Acc2 |   201906 | 201908
A     |     1 |                 0 | Acc2 |   201909 | 201912
A     |     1 |                10 | Acc2 |   202001 | 202004
A     |     1 |                 0 | Acc2 |   202005 | 202009
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables and then use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT code,
       rate1,
       rate2,
       type,
       first_month,
       last_month
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.code,
         t1.rate1,
         COALESCE( t2.rate2, 0 ) AS rate2,
         t1.type,
         t1.month
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
         ON ( t1.code = t2.code AND t1.month = t2.month )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY type
   ORDER BY month
   MEASURES
      FIRST( code ) AS code,
      FIRST( rate1 ) AS rate1,
      FIRST( rate2 ) AS rate2,
      FIRST( month ) AS first_month,
      LAST( month ) AS last_month
   ONE ROW PER MATCH
   PATTERN (FIRST_ROW SAME_RATES*)
   DEFINE
      SAME_RATES AS (    SAME_RATES.rate1 = PREV(SAME_RATES.rate1)
                     AND SAME_RATES.rate2 = PREV(SAME_RATES.rate2) )
)
ORDER BY type, first_month;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( CODE, RATE1, type, MONTH ) AS
SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc1', 201906 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc1', 201907 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc1', 201908 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 201909 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 201910 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 201911 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 201912 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202004 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202005 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202006 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202007 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202008 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc1', 202009 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc2', 201906 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc2', 201907 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 0, 'Acc2', 201908 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 201909 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 201910 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 201911 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 201912 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202004 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202005 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202006 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202007 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202008 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Acc2', 202009 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( CODE, RATE2, MONTH ) AS
SELECT 'A', 10, 202001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 10, 202002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 10, 202003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 10, 202004 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE | RATE1 | RATE2 | TYPE | FIRST_MONTH | LAST_MONTH
> :--- | ----: | ----: | :--- | ----------: | ---------:
> A    |     0 |     0 | Acc1 |      201906 |     201908
> A    |     1 |     0 | Acc1 |      201909 |     201912
> A    |     1 |    10 | Acc1 |      202001 |     202004
> A    |     1 |     0 | Acc1 |      202005 |     202009
> A    |     0 |     0 | Acc2 |      201906 |     201908
> A    |     1 |     0 | Acc2 |      201909 |     201912
> A    |     1 |    10 | Acc2 |      202001 |     202004
> A    |     1 |     0 | Acc2 |      202005 |     202009
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e32dcbfc50fbdda8c9d41240229bb27f)*